# Handlebars: objects with functions and the each helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have an object like this, with a private array and public method to get it.

```
var obj = function(){
   var fooArray = ["b","a","r"];
   var fooVar = "bar";

   this.getFooVar = function(){
       return fooVar;
   }
   this.getFooArray = function(){
       return foo;
   }
}
```

And I will pass a new instance of that function as context to a handlebars template.
In order to read the public getFooVar I had to write a handlebars helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getParam', function(model,param){

    if(typeof model == "undefined"){
        return '';
    }
    return model['get'+ucfirst(param)]();
});
```

So now I can `{{getParam fooObject 'fooVar'}} // outputs "bar"`

But what if I wanted to iterate over the fooArray?
I've explored setting variables inside of handlebar templates, which seems like a no go. I've reviewed the source each helper function, but it is too complex for me.

I've done some research, now I need some help.

How to iterate over a object's function result in handlebars.js?

Comment: You cannot pipe responses in Handlebars. One helper is all you get.

Comment: So is my best bet to make variables public or is there a workaround

Comment: Maybe you can make a pipe helper? That will call helperB with the result from helperA, but it will be messy. All helpers are stored on `Handlebars.helpers.xxx`

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I will just write a toContext function on my models and have it give my templates easier access to variables

Answer (score 0):

**Subexpressions**

Handlebars offers support for subexpressions, which allows you to invoke multiple helpers within a single mustache, and pass in the results of inner helper invocations as arguments to outer helpers. Subexpressions are delimited by parentheses.

{{outer-helper (inner-helper 'abc') 'def'}}
In this case, inner-helper will get invoked with the string argument 'abc', and whatever the inner-helper function returns will get passed in as the first argument to outer-helper (and 'def' will get passed in as the second argument to outer-helper).

See documentation here: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions